# Best Practices for fetching json from server for android app

Tags: android, json, performance

I have an Android app with 1 activity and 3 fragment opened in tablayout.
When a user open the app, the mainActivity fetch a json file from the server to check if the app version still in use and the first fragment fetch also a separate json file to feed the views. Every fragement fetch a separate json file to feed the there views with data.
The problem that I have is, that when the app has more than 100 active user, the json file did not get loaded and the okhttp get a timeOutException when trying to fetch the json file from the server. Basically when a user open the app, 4 json files will be fetched from the server, so I think the server has problem responding to all the requests.
So my question, what is the best practice to resolve such a performance problem, beside upgrading the server itself.
Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to have a request queue. Volley does that for you and it's quite easy to implement. Use the same request queue and implement 4 JsonRequests using it's model (https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple). But keep in mind to have the same queue.

Comment: I'm using okHttp for the network connection. Does it also have the request queue, or do you recommend volley for this kind of tasks ?

Comment: I would recommend Volley, or if you use RX-Java, Retrofit has some useful features. You can however implement that queue mechanism on your own for the okHttp requests. But the easy way is to simply use Volley. Also have in mind it might be a server side issue, maybe your API isn't well implemented and the response time exceeds the timeout of the httpConnection. You can increase the timeout to let's say...30seconds if you haven't done this already.

Comment: ok thank you for the help.